# What is the unit of measurement for buffer calculation?

Tags: geometry, java, buffer, geotools

What is the unit of measurement used by Geometry class for it's buffer calculation ?
Api doc currently defines it as " distance - the width of the buffer (may be positive, negative or 0)"

I need to draw polygons around a given Geometry with X miles away. Wondering if there is an easy way to do it with current set of GeoTools API.

Api :  http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#buffer(double)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to post it as comment but it seems to me like your are looking for this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83199/buffer-zip-region-polygon-with-geotools?answertab=votes#tab-top In this case I have a polygon and want to buffer it with a meter distance so you can adapt it easily for miles I guess.

Answer (score 5):

The units of measurement is based on the underlying spatial reference. So, for example, if it is [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) it is decimal degrees or if it [EPSG:2037](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2037/) it is meters.

Comment: I tried the following code with GeoTools api CRSAuthorityFactory   factory = CRS.getAuthorityFactory(true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = factory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:2037");             I get an exception as follows : org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Unit conversion from "DMS" to "°" is non-linear.