# Buffer Zip Region Polygon with GeoTools

Tags: buffer, coordinate-system, geotools

What I want to achieve is to buffer a zip region geometry with a distance in meters and than get the coordinates of the new (expanded) polygon. The original geometry polygon is parsed from a kml file.

This is the code that I wrote so far:

Parse the kml file:

```
public Geometry getPolygon(String plz) {
  String poly = storage.get(plz);

  if (poly != null) {
    try {
      InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(poly.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      Parser parser = new Parser(new KMLConfiguration());
      SimpleFeature f = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse(stream);

      return (Geometry) f.getAttribute("GEOMETRY");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Transform the polygon:

```
public Geometry getBufferedZipPolygon(Geometry zipPolygon, double distanceMeters) {
  CoordinateReferenceSystem wgsCRS = null;
  CoordinateReferenceSystem distanceMetersCRS = null;
  try {
    wgsCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    distanceMetersCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:32630");

    Geometry targetGeometry = zipPolygon.transform(distanceMetersCRS);

    Geometry buffer = targetGeometry.getBuffer(distanceMeters);
    buffer.transform(wgsCRS);

    return buffer;
  } catch (FactoryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TransformException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  }

  return null;
}
```

I have two Questions now. Is this transformation valid and how can I get the new Coordinates from my transformed Geometry Object?

Answer:

With the help from iant I finally figured out this solution.

Parser:

```
public Polygon getPolygon(String plz) {
  String polyString = storage.get(plz);

  if (polyString != null) {
    try {
      InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(polyString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      Parser parser = new Parser(new KMLConfiguration());
      Polygon polygon = (Polygon) parser.parse(stream);
      return polygon;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Transformation:

```
public Geometry getBufferedZipPolygon(Polygon zipPolygon, double distanceMeters) {
  CoordinateReferenceSystem wgsCRS;
  CoordinateReferenceSystem distanceMetersCRS;
  try {
    wgsCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
    distanceMetersCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:32630", true);

    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(wgsCRS, distanceMetersCRS);
    MathTransform reverseTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(distanceMetersCRS, wgsCRS);

    Geometry transformedZipPolygon = JTS.transform(zipPolygon, transform);
    Geometry bufferZipPolygon = transformedZipPolygon.buffer(distanceMeters);

    return JTS.transform(bufferZipPolygon, reverseTransform);
  } catch (FactoryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TransformException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return null;
}
```

Get the coordinates:

```
bufferedPlzPolygon = (Polygon) getBufferedZipPolygon(plzPolyStorage.getPolygon(zip), range);
Coordinate[] coords = bufferedPlzPolygon.getCoordinates();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that transform (and provided that it doesn't throw an exception it works ok).

To recover the coordinates you will need to do:

```
Polygon poly  = (Polygon) buffer;
Coordinate[] coords = poly.getCoordinates();
```

Technically you should do some checks to make sure it is a polygon before you cast it and make sure nothing is null etc but this should get you started.

Comment: What type of Geometry Object did you use? Because I get the Error can't resolve getDefaultGeometryProperty()...

I am using the `org.opengis.geometry.Geometry` and 
`org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.Polygon`

Comment: I would use a JTS Polygon

Comment: But a JTS Polygon doesnt have the `getDefaultGeometryProperty()` method neither. Do I need a specific build?

Comment: sorry - I thought you were working from a feature. Just cast your Geometry to a Polygon